# Subset class sfc_LINESTRING & sfc objects within a bbox

Tags: r, dataframe, geospatial, r-sf

Example:

```
bbox <- c(-0.1178, 51.4232, -0.0185, 51.5147) # I know it needs to be sf df object
# we have 
df
#> Geometry set for 300 features 
#> geometry type:  LINESTRING
#> dimension:      XY
#> bbox:           xmin: -0.113894 ymin: 51.49739 xmax: -0.0764779 ymax: 51.59839
#> epsg (SRID):    4326
#> proj4string:    +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs
#> LINESTRING (-0.113894 51.50631, -0.1135137 51.5...
#> LINESTRING (-0.0767875 51.59837, -0.0764779 51....
#> ....
```

How can I do something like

```
df[bbox]
```

and keep the linestrings which are within the bbox. Thanks.

Comment: Sounds like `st_crop`? See some discussion on the [GIS board](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/230900/crop-simple-features-object-in-r)

Comment: Awesome @camille, duplicate or would you like to just put in this and I will accept it as the correct answer

`sf::st_crop(df, c(xmin=-0.1178, ymin=51.4232, xmax=-0.0185, ymax=51.5147))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's an example using an `sf` object from `tigris`, just for reproducibility. I'm using towns in New Haven County, Connecticut, plotting it the way it comes in. Then I crop it to a bounding box I made up, using `st_crop`, which I believe was added fairly recently to `sf`. If I had the bbox as a shape, instead of a vector of coordinates, I could have used `st_intersection`.

I don't have a linestring object handy, but I'd assume it works the same way.

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(sf)

# selecting just to limit the amount of data in my sf
ct_sf <- tigris::county_subdivisions(state = "09", county = "09", cb = T, class = "sf") %>%
  select(NAME, geometry)

plot(ct_sf)
```

[image]

```r
crop_bbox <- c(xmin = -73, ymin = 41.2, xmax = -72.7, ymax = 41.5)
ct_cropped <- st_crop(ct_sf, crop_bbox)

plot(ct_cropped)
```

[image]

Comment: Pretty answer thanks! Better track `sf` developments closely.